# How to convert FileStorage object to b2sdk.v2.AbstractUploadSource in Python

Tags: python, forms, file, upload, backblaze

I am using [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) and [b2sdk.v2](https://b2-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/) in Flask to upload files.

This is code I tried, using the [`upload`](https://b2-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/bucket.html#b2sdk.v2.Bucket.upload) method:

```
# I am not showing authorization code...
def upload_file(file):
  bucket = b2_api.get_bucket_by_name(bucket_name)
  file = request.files['file']
  bucket.upload(
        upload_source=file,
        file_name=file.filename,
    )
```

This shows an error like this

```
AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'get_content_length'
```

I think it's because I am using a `FileStorage` instance for the `upload_source` parameter.

I want to know whether I am using the API correctly or, if not, how should I use this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - you can't use a Flask `FileStorage` instance as a B2 SDK `UploadSource`. What you need to do is to use the [`upload_bytes`](https://b2-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/bucket.html#b2sdk.v2.Bucket.upload_bytes) method with the file's content:

```
def upload_file(file):
  bucket = b2_api.get_bucket_by_name(bucket_name)
  file = request.files['file']
  bucket.upload_bytes(
        data_bytes=file.read(),
        file_name=file.filename,
        ...other parameters...
    )
```

Note that **this reads the entire file into memory**. The `upload_bytes` method may need to restart the upload if something goes wrong (with the network, usually), so the file can't really be streamed straight through into B2.

If you anticipate that your files will not fit into memory, you should look at using [`create_file_stream`](https://b2-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/bucket.html#b2sdk.v2.Bucket.create_file_stream) to upload the file in chunks.